# Dynamic load items in a list using thymeleaf + angular + bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, thymeleaf

Hi guys I continue with my code and I have a problem that someone can maybe help me to fix it.
I'm using UI Bootstrap with angular and thymeleaf and I have problems to comunicate each. I want this:

[image]

So this table is loading dynamic from Thymeleaf but the name provider need to change.

Here is the code:

```
<accordion-group heading="{{providerGroup}}" th:attr="ng-repeat=\''+ providerGroup in ${@provider.getProviders().keySet()}+'\')'">
                {{providerName}}
            </accordion-group>
```

everything is working fine except that I dont know why thymeleaf dont read it.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
            <li th:each="provider : ${@provider.getProviders().keySet()}">              
            <accordion-group th:attr="heading=${provider}" ng-model="providerSelected">
                {{providerSelected}}

                <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="addItem()">Add Item</button>
                <div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</div>
            </accordion-group>
            </li>   
        </accordion>
```

Enjoy it!